# 2 rows of elements in a horizontally scrollable container

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

How to position elements of different widths in 2 rows **in a horizontally scrollable container** using CSS only?

[image]

Seems like a simple task. But:

- I need them in the following order:

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8...
```

- The amount of children elements is variable (*so you can't set fixed width*)
- Ideally want it done under single wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
   ....
</div>
```

I am almost there but not quite:
https://codepen.io/maxflex/pen/abwdgJo

---

**UPD.** thanks to @TemaniAfif I'm even closer now, just need to get rid of fixed width:
https://codepen.io/maxflex/pen/ExXmvxo

Comment: Were you able to find the generic answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper * {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

/* a hidden element to create a seperation 
   between the 1st and 2nd row */
.wrapper:before {
  content:"";
  flex-basis:100%;
  order:1
}
/* place the even item at the second row */
.wrapper *:nth-child(even) {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>All</div>
  <div>Cell Phones</div>
  <div>Back to school</div>
  <div>Toys</div>
  <div>Grocery</div>
  <div>TV and Home Theater</div>
  <div>Movies and Music</div>
  <div>Games</div>
  <div>Audio</div>
  <div>Smart home</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's smart! Thank you. I tried to apply it for my project and found that when there's many children elements, the amount of rows expectedly start to grow since the width is limited by the width of the parent container. I reformulated the problem a little

Answer (score 0):

This works

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.wrapper > * {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>All</div> 
  <div>Back to school</div>
  <div>Grocery</div>
  <div>Movies and Music</div>
  <div>Audio</div>
  <div>Cell Phones</div>
  <div>Toys</div> 
  <div>TV and Home Theater</div>  
  <div>Games</div>  
  <div>Smart home</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: It's easier to re-arrange the divs in the '.wrapper' than to use "order" properties for the wrapper's children.

Comment: thanks for the answer! But this isn't what I was looking for because 1) the order is wrong 2)  it only works for fixed width, but the amount of children elements is variable